# How to avoid performance degradation when run query with cast in where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan, entity-attribute-value

I have a table with 2 varchar columns (name and value)
and I have such a query:

```
select * from attribute
where name = 'width' and cast( value as integer) > 12
```

This query works but I suppose there are could be an issue with execution plan because of index build over value column because it is technically varchar but we convert it to integer.

Are there ways to fix it ?

**P.S.** I can't change type to int because the database design implies that value could be any type.

Comment: Using an EAV model in such a way is not best for performance, a few tricks can help, depending on your RDBMS - which you haven't tagged.

Comment: @Stu added  postgresql tag

Comment: @Stu will it help if I add separated table for each type(varchar/int/float) ?

I am afraid huge amount of joins

Answer (score 0):

Performance should not be your first worry here.

Your statement is prone to failures. You read this as:

1. read all rows with name = 'width'
2. of these rows cast all values to integer and only keep those with a value graeter than 12

But the DBMS is free to check conditions in the `WHERE` clause in any order. If the DBMS does that:

1. cast all values to integer and only keep the rows with a value graeter than 12
2. of these rows keep all with name = 'width'

the first step will already cause a runtime error, if there is a non-integer value in that table, which is likely.

So first get your query safe. The following should work:

```
select *
from
(
  select * 
  from attribute
  where name = 'width'
) widths
where cast(value as integer) > 12;
```

This will still fail, when your width contains non-integers. So, to get this even safe in case of invalid data in the table, you may want to add a check that the value only contains digits in the subquery.

And yes, this won't become super-fast. You sacrifice speed (and data consistency checks) for flexibility with this data model.

What you can do, however, is create an index on both columns, so the DBMS can quickly find all width rows and then have the value directly at hand, before it accesses the table:

```
create index idx on attribute (name, value);
```

As far as I know, there is no fail-safe cast function in PostgreSQL. Otherwise you could use this and have a function index instead. I may be wrong, so maybe someone can come up with a better solution here.

Comment: Will index work for a varchar column if we cast it to integer ?

Comment: The index's main purpose is to get the width rows quickly and provide the value right away. Thus the DBMS can find the width rows and cast the value in order to apply `where cast(value as integer) > 12` *before* accessing the table. So, yes, the index is a good means to help the DBMS to run this query fast. Of course it is not as fast as it would be were the column numeric.

Comment: Kettne

Is there any performance comparison
1. Without index
2. with index but with cast to integer
3. with index and withuout cast 
?

Comment: No. It's slow -> faster -> fastest. If you want to measure times, just create test tables and indexes and try.

Comment: To be honest I can't understand how index can help in case if use cast. Index sorts rows according to natural order. For strings and for numbers this order is different. How could it accelerate search ?

Comment: You look for the name 'width'. How long would it take you to find a person with the last name 'Width' in a telephone book? How long would it take you, if the telephone book were not ordered by last name? Well, in a database it's just the same, the table contains the unordered data while the index is sorted. Unlike a telephone book, though, index and table in a database are two separate things. More like a glossar in a book hence where the glossar has the words ordered and tells you where to find them in the book. So let's say that darn telephone book has two parts, the index ordered by last...

Comment: ...name and first name and the entries. With the index you find the name (sometimes one, sometimes many as with 'John Smith') and see on which page and position you find the entries containing the telephone number and address. Now, you are not looking for a person with the last name 'Width' only, but there is a second condition on their first name. Unfortunately, this condition is not first name = 'Anne', which would be super-quick, because the index would tell you exactly which entries to look up: find 'Width' in the index, then within 'Width' find 'Anne', then look up the entry or entries...

Comment: ...Your second condition is not that straight-forward. It is casting in your case, but let's keep an example where we are looking for first names that contain 'nn'. Wouldn't the index still be very helpful? You'd still find all persons names 'Width' right away. And you'd see their first names. The order of the first names within 'Width' doesn't help you, but you can read them sequentially. You'd find 'Anne' and look up their entry, because this name contains 'nn'. You'd find 'Bill' and not look up the entry. You'd find 'Winnie' and look up the entry.

Comment: Hope that finally helps you understand what is happening in the database when using this index.